# Jupyter Notebook launch fail from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am getting the following error message on launching Jupyter Notebook. I did conda update all already, but to no avail.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-Notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, date_default
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/jsonutil.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That is a Python2-only syntax, so probably you did something very wrong with your Python environment. Try uninstalling and reinstalling that package; or just uninstall and reinstall everything, or upgrade all the packages..

Answer (score 0):

Would probably need a little mote information on how you're trying to launch it, on what system and what program etc. But assuming you have conda installed and the environment activated via `conda activate my_env_path_name`, you should be able to launch jupyter notebooks by typing `jupyter notebook`